# Ubuntu 18.04 New Netplan / IP Configuration (pointopoint?) (Need Example)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ifconfig, ipconfig, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Root-Server with Proxmox installed. Until now, i always had Ubuntu 16. Now i upgraded a VM to Ubuntu 18 and i need a example for the new netplan Configuration.

This was my old interfaces file:

```
auto ens18
iface ens18 inet static
    address 195.201.52.XXX
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    pointopoint 195.201.8.YYY
    gateway 195.201.8.YYY
    dns-nameservers 213.133.98.98 213.133.99.99 213.133.100.100 8.8.8.8
```

Because i couldn't find the option pointopoint with the new netplan i'm struggeling to activate this VM. I know i could simply install ifupdown again. But if there is a possibillity i would like to keep the new netplan. Could anyone help me out with this ?

Thanks in advance, Roger

=== Some more Informations ===
Have a look at my Configuration Files: https://pastebin.com/Havqfw7t
IPv4 Forwarding is enabled on both Guest and Host System.
Hopefully you can help me with having a look at my COnfiguration Files.

Answer (score 3):

Netplan does not seem to support address attributes such as "peer", but the same result can be achieved in other ways, as for broadcast interfaces it just emulates an on-link route.

NOTE: This is a wild guess and I don't actually have an Ubuntu machine to test any of it on.

If you're lucky and Netplan is smart enough, it'll work with this configuration:

```
addresses: ["195.201.52.XXX/32"]
gateway4: "195.201.52.YYY"
```

If not, then a manually configured route to the gateway should do:

```
addresses: ["195.201.52.XXX/32"]
gateway4: "195.201.52.YYY"
routes:
  - {to: "195.201.52.YYY/32", on-link: true}
```

Or a manually configured default route:

```
addresses: ["195.201.52.XXX/32"]
routes:
  - {to: "0.0.0.0/0", via: "195.201.52.YYY/32", on-link: true}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your anwser. I tried all 3 options:
1. Didn't work
2. Error: a Route needs both a "to" and "via" parameter.
3. Somehow also doesn't work. I'm not able to ping anything (also not gateway).

I'm Posting some more Infotmations in the main Post. May you can look at it again ?